# Trouble with reading from a table in a database using Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, sql, spring-boot, jstl

I have a database with an existing table. I was able to connect the database successfully to the Spring Boot program in IntelliJ, but I am having trouble populating an html table with the data in the database.

This is my Events class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "startdate")
    private String startdate;
    @Column(name = "enddate")
    private String enddate;

    public Events(){

    }

    public Events(int id, String description, String startdate, String enddate){
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.startdate = startdate;
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getStartdate() {
        return startdate;
    }

    public void setStartdate(String startdate) {
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }

    public String getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(String enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }
}
```

This is my Main Controller

```
import Models.Events;
import Models.EventsRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    EventsRepo eventsRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView doHome(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("eventslist", eventsRepo.findAll());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

And this is my index.jps file:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 3</title>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Events Table</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Event Description</th>
        <th>Start Date and Time</th>
        <th>End Date and Time</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var = "events" items = "${eventslist}">
        <tr>
            <td>${events.getDescription()}</td>
            <td>${events.getStartdate()}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem has to be in this part of the code:

```
<c:forEach var = "events" items = "${eventslist}">
        <tr>
            <td>${events.getDescription()}</td>
            <td>${events.getStartdate()}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

I tested that forEach loop using just

```
<td>test</td>
```

But it still did not populate the web app when I refreshed it. I went through different lectures my professor gave and combed through his code as well. The forEach code is something he taught us, but for some reason it is not given me the same result.

I've tested the connection to the database and it works. I've also linked the database to mySQL workbench to make sure the table I'm looking for exists and that it is populated with data. It does exist and is has 15 rows of data.

Any help or guidance to what I can read or look at would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.   Offhand, try it without the spaces around the "=" signs - ie: `<c:forEach var="events" items="${eventslist}">` .  This is because JSTL is mimicking HTML or XML, so it's not like Java code where whitespaces are effectively ignored.

Comment: Just tried it, and no dice. It still doesn't populate anything. I also tried to writing <td>hello</td> inside of the forEach loop. Just to see if it is going through it and prints "hello" in the table rows. It did not print hello or the data from the table.

Comment: Next step is to see if it’s a problem with the query or the display - so extract the `eventsRepo.findAll());` into a List variable so that you can examine the list size.

Comment: I am honestly not sure how to do that. Would I just create a List object in my main controller? When I try to do that and preform list.add(), it just has errors.

Comment: Just have `List<Events> EventList = eventsRepo.findAll();  mv.addObject("eventslist", eventList); ` .  You can then set a breakpoint on the addObject call so you see the size of eventList.

Comment: `ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<Events> eventsList = (List<Events>) eventsRepo.findAll();
        //mv.addObject("eventslist", eventsRepo.findAll());
        mv.addObject("eventslist", eventsList);
        return mv;
`

So this is what I changed it to. It typecasted to (List<Events>) to fix that line of code. When I run it, the springboot site is still blank (other than the table headers)

Comment: Great, now what size is eventsList ?  Eg you can put a breakpoint so you can examine it, or put a `System.out.println(“Size=“+eventsList.size());”.

Comment: So I tried using System.out.println to see the size of the eventsList, but nothing prints to console. I checked the log and it is also empty. I wrote the line inside of the doHom() function

Comment: System.out.println would go to the console - so if you’re not seeing any output that implies to me that it’s not hitting that method (and hence why there’s no list being displayed). Can you edit the question to show the full name (including path and extension) of your index file, and the URL you are using?  Thanks

Comment: I updated the question with the full index code. I have it named "index.jsp" and that's it. I actually reached out to my professor to see if he had anything he could add. When he runs my code and visits localhost:8088, he actually sees the html table populated with information from my database.


He thinks it might have something to do with java version? When I initially used the spring initializer webstie, I used version 2.3.5 and java 11. Just sharing this information in case it helps too. I tried running it again this morning and I still can't see anything when I visit the port number.